# AsyncTask crashes after first line?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am trying to build an application that calls a webservice through an AsyncTask, however, the app always crashes after the first line of the AsyncTask. Below is my code for the AsyncTask:

```
 protected class AsyncGetItemByKey extends AsyncTask<String, JSONObject, ItemTable> {

    String userName=null;
    @Override
    protected ItemTable doInBackground(String... params) {
        itemTable = null;
        //send the application context for preference retrieval
        //RestAPI api = new RestAPI(getApplicationContext());
        RestAPI api = RestAPI.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = api.GetHMMItemByKey(params[0],params[1]);
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            itemTable = parser.parseItem(jsonObj);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.d("AsyncUserDetails", e.getMessage());
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
        return itemTable;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        //Toast.makeText(context, "Please Wait...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ItemTable itemTable) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

And this is how I call the AsyncTask when a button is pressed:

```
new AsyncGetItemByKey().execute(itemNumber, siteID);
```

I put a breakpoint inside my AsyncTask and after the first line userName=null, the app crashes. Below is the log as well:

```
05-26 16:16:34.600    3323-3323/com.binarystream.bssiapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.binarystream.bssiapp, PID: 3323
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
        at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:101)
        at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:250)
        at com.binarystream.bssiapp.SupplyReqMaintenanceActivity$1.onClick(SupplyReqMaintenanceActivity.java:91)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

I know something must be null, but I can't figure out what it is. I also tried itemTable = new ItemTable() instead of null but that did not help.

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: If I am reading the stacktrace correctly, it is because of a Toast, so I would guess that the context is null. In your code you commented the toast in the OnPreExecute method, so do you use a toast anywhere else? And where do you initialize the context there?

Comment: Can you post RestAPI

Comment: Is this an inner class within an `Activity`? Couldn't you just use `SupplyReqMaintenanceActivity.this` rather than `getApplicationContext()`?

Comment: @mrtn yes I did have one other Toast, commented that one out and the error went away but it is still crashing at the first line of the Async Task

Comment: @karaokyo yes, it is an inner class. I will try replacing as you said

Comment: Where do you declare `itemTable`?

Comment: @DanielNugent I declare itemTable in the Activity that calls the AsyncTask.

Now there is no error in the LogCat but the app still crashes after the first line of the AsyncTask. Interestingly enough, in the LogCat I can see the returned JSON value of the webservice, which was successful...so it must have called the web service before it crashed? The returned value is correct.

Comment: You might have a problem there, as `itemTable` is also a local variable in `onPostExecute()`.  Either declare it in the enclosing Activity, or pass it into `onPostExecute()`, but don't do both.  Also, can you post your updated log output?

Comment: but you have a try catch in your doinbackground and it still crash? without an error? do you have codes in your onpostexecute?

Comment: @DanielNugent thanks! that worked, I just renamed the itemTable in the AsyncTask and parsed my JSON into this new object. All works now. If you make that an answer, I can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues in the code in the question.

The first issue is the calls to `getApplicationContext()` in the AsyncTask.  The reason that this doesn't work is because when you call `getApplicationContext()`, it's really short for `this.getApplicationContext()`.  The reason that this will work in an [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) is that it extends [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html), which is the class that contains the `getApplicationContext()` method.
Since [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) does not extent `Context`, you cannot use `this` as a `Context`.

Instead, just replace it with `SupplyReqMaintenanceActivity.this`, which you can use as a `Context`.  Note that you could also call `SupplyReqMaintenanceActivity.this.getApplicationContext()`, and that would be valid as well.

Just be sure to use the Activity Context and Application Context appropriately, and know the difference between them.

The second issue is that the `itemTable` is declared in the `SupplyReqMaintenanceActivity` Activity, but it's also a local variable in the `onPostExecute()` method, as the name of the parameter passed in.  You cannot have multiple variables with the same name in the same scope.

To fix that, just rename the local variable that has scope in the AsyncTask so that it doesn't conflict with the `itemTable` variable that is declared in the Activity.